# setNavigationBarHidden not working on iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios15, xcode13

I'm having troubles with the method `setNavigationBarHidden`, it doesn't seem to work properly on **iOS 15**.

I am currently working with this structure:

1. A `ViewController`, which needs the `navigationBar`
2. Another `ViewController`, pushed from the previous when I tap a `UIButton`, which doesn't need the `navigationBar`

On the previous versions of **iOS**, I simply called `setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)` in the `viewWillAppear` method of the second `ViewController` and everything worked as expected but, from the new version of iOS, that doesn't occur correctly.

Now the `navigationBar` doesn't hide properly and, the only way I have to achieve the behavior I want, is by using the `navigationBar.isHidden = true`, which unfortunately leads me in a sloppy and not so smooth animation between the two controllers.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I regard this as a bug in iOS 15.

Answer (score 6):

You need simply add

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
navigationBar.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: It works and I'd mark it as a solution, thanks man.
Using `DispatchQueue.main.async` is a common approach to ensure that UI updates are performed on the main thread, avoiding potential synchronization issues.
It appears that in iOS 15 there are other animations or UI operations going on, calling `setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)` may not take effect immediately. Changes may be delayed or overridden by subsequent operations, resulting in a situation where the navigation bar is not hidden as expected.

Answer (score -2):

```swift
    /// 针对iOS15
    /// 适配导航栏隐藏
    static func configureNavgationBarStyle() {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            navigationBarAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
            UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        }
    }
```

> Calling this method in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` methods or other place you want, then the problem will disappear.

Comment: No, that had no effect on the behavior of `setNavigationBarHidden`.